# Liquibase changeset with only preConditions

Tags: sql, liquibase

I need to add `changeSet` with only `preConditions` tag and if it failed then stop execute. This is my changeset:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.3.xsd">
    <changeSet id="GEO-6154_2" author="kadzhaev">
            <preConditions onFail="HALT">
                <sqlCheck expectedResult="0">select count(*) from "public"."messages" where key = 'branding.region.oktmo' and value != '';</sqlCheck>
            </preConditions>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

but it doesn't work cause:
`liquibase: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'preConditions'.` I think I should add some tag after `preConditions` but I do not need it. How to solve this problem?

Comment: What's exact version of your liquibase? Please post your whole  `databaseChangeLog` opening tag. Also: are you 100% sure error is caused by pasted snippet and not anything else in your changelog? Is changelog without this one `changeSet` working?

Comment: @RadekPostołowicz, I am using 3.3.1 version. I updated my post, look. Yes, I'm 100% sure because if I remove this `changeSet` then all works fine

Comment: Your posted xml is perfectly valid against schema (http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.3.xsd). If you take a look there, you can see that `changeSet` has defined a few children and none of them is required. I also checked it empirically and it works with 3.3.1 version for me. Maybe you have some crazy whitespace characters in your file?